# Unsigned int not giving expected value

Tags: c, gcc

I'm reading 2 bytes from a file and trying to use the unsigned int as an ID for my SVG output.

```
unsigned int character_name_1;
unsigned int character_name_2;

fread( buffer, sizeof( char ), 4, fpi );
character_name_1=(((buffer[1]<<8)+buffer[0])&0xFFFF);
character_name_2=(((buffer[3]<<8)+buffer[2])&0xFFFF);
```

If the file has 2 values 126 and 128 which are 0x007E and 0x0080 (buffer[0]=0x7E and buffer[1]=0x00), then, if I print out to my SVG file `<g id=%u d=%s></g>",character_name_1, pathdata);`, then I get the id correctly recorded as 'id="126"'.

However, the second value is problematic:`<g id=%u d=%s></g>",character_name_2, pathdata);` gives me the following entry: 'id="65408"'

The next value, which has the 2 bytes 0xA0 and 0x00, which I am expecting to be 160 is written as 65440. 0xA1 and 0x00 should be 161, but I'm getting 65441.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Is buffer a char array?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of `buffer`. Thanks.

Comment: You're not showing all of your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `buffer` is probably a signed type (`char`).

This causes the value `0xA1` to be interepeted as a negative number and automatic sign extension is invoked (`0xA1` -> `0xFFA1`), to make sure the sum (`buffer[3]<<8 + buffer[2]`) is handled correctly. So you get the value of `0xFFA1`, which is 65441.

Changing buffer to `unsigned char` will solve your issue.

Comment: Using `fread(&character_name_1, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, fpi);` followed by `fread(&character_name_2, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, fpi);`

Comment: Actually, if `character_name_1` is `unsigned int` and not `unsigned short`, I need some intermediate variable. so you can do `fread(&character_name_1_short, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, fpi); character_name_1 = (unsigned int)character_name_1_short;`

Comment: You are right, endianness is not handled correctly. Fixing my answer...

Comment: Thank you. This business of signed character values from the input file was a bit of a surprise to me as I was expecting to handle the twos compliment of negative bytes manually. It finally makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` is declared with `char` or `signed char`. Change it to `unsigned char`.

Because the elements in your `buffer` are signed, you are getting negative values in your expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Not much clear from your question, assuming buffer is array of character or character pointer. I think following change should work:

```
character_name_1=(((buffer[1]<<8)+buffer[0])&0xFF);
character_name_2=(((buffer[3]<<8)+buffer[2])&0xFF);
```

Comment: That's equal to `character_name_1= buffer[0] & 0xFF;`, you are throwing away the other byte.